# Create table using select statement Truncated incorrect datetime value:

Tags: mysql, temporary-tables, date-format, truncate

I have looked up different answers on similar question before posting it here.

So i have a table with user id and date column

[image]

I would like to store the results of select query to a temporary table. 
On using the below statement:

Create Temporary table dummy_table (
select User_Id , DATE_FORMAT(`Date`,'%M %Y') 
from result_table.user_signup_date );

throws error 
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-06-16 00:00:00 UTC'

I noticed the error occurs only when i format date column. I tried converting date to string. I also tried with str_to_date(DATE_FORMAT(`Date`,'%M %Y') ,'%M %Y %H:%i:%s') and few more syntaxes but with no result.

I am new to Sql. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the error message, the `UTC` should not be part of the `date`. My guess is that `date` is not using the `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` data type. It must be a string.

Try running it like this :

```
Create table dummy_table AS
select Cust_ID User_Id , DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(`Date`,19),'%M %Y') DT
from result_table.user_signup_date;
```

The expression `LEFT(Date,19)` will drop off the everything after the timestamp.

Comment: Wow. This works. I wish i could have posted it earlier. 
Thank you!

Comment: Just Curious. 
If 'Date' column is read as string by SQL, how does it work when i use DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%M %Y'). Am i missing any basics here?